# Material UI - Autocomplete form labels with 2 variables

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do you show both title and year in the label of the autocomplete form?

This is the standard Material UI demo. When I try to use an array to show both title and year in the form label, I get an error about lowercasing the results. I think that's because the value isn't a string anymore - but I can't see how to fix that.

```
<Autocomplete
      multiple
      id="checkboxes-tags-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      disableCloseOnSelect
      getOptionLabel={(option) => [{option.title}, {option.year}]}  // - this doesn't work
      renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Checkbox
            icon={icon}
            checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
            style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
            checked={selected}
          />
          //[{option.title}, {option.year}] - this doesn't work
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
      style={{ width: 500 }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" label="Checkboxes" placeholder="Favorites" />
      )}
    />
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { title: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
  { title: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 },
```

Answer (score 0):

So - the solution is to leave the options tag alone (just the title) and then use both title and year in the checkbox tag as follows:

{option.title} <span style={{paddingRight: 3px}} /> {option.year}

I don't understand why this works but it does.